# наследование свойств view элементов с другого класса

Tags: xcode, swift

Есть следующий код в ViewHelper классе, от которого будет наследоваться градиент бэкграунд на все экраны :

```
class ViewHelper: UIViewController{
class func SetBackGroundColor(view: UIView){
    let startColor = UIColor(red:0.84, green:0.82, blue:0.80, alpha:1.0)
    let endColor = UIColor(red:0.19, green:0.26, blue:0.32, alpha:1.0)
    let newLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    newLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor,endColor.cgColor]
    newLayer.frame = view.frame
    view.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
}
```

Вот теперь я хочу в другом классе забрать от него этот цвет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопросик нубовский, но извините, после АдроидСтудии как то тяжеловато в Xcode.))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно зачем Вы наследуетесь от `UIViewController` в `ViewHelper`. Ошибка возникла потому что функция ожидает `UIView`, а Вы передаете `UIViewController`.

Варианты решения:

1 передавайте UIView

```
ViewHelper.setBackgroundColor(view: self.view) //соблюдайте camelCase
```

2 получайте его:

```
class func setBackgroundColor(_ controller: UIViewController) {
    //view заменяете на controller.view
```

3 используйте extension:

```
// Из Вашего кода:
extension UIView {
    func addGradient() {
        let startColor = UIColor(red:0.84, green:0.82, blue:0.80, alpha:1.0)
        let endColor = UIColor(red:0.19, green:0.26, blue:0.32, alpha:1.0)
        let newLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        newLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor,endColor.cgColor]
        newLayer.frame = frame
        layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
    }
}

// Применение:
view.addGradient()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за очень крутой ответ!